# htaccess multiple get values

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

```
RewriteRule ^admin/load/loadSearch/([a-fA-F0-9])/([a-fA-F0-9])$ admin/load/loadsearch.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/load/loaddSearch/([a-fA-F0-9])/([a-fA-F0-9])/(.*)$ admin/load/loadsearch.php?type=$1&id=$2&lname=$3 [L]
```

it is not working please help me ..the third get value is optional

Comment: Please describe what exactly is not working. What do you want to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: 404 error showing ... i want to get the third get element also .. but in 2 case it worked ...

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/load/loadSearch/([a-fA-F0-9])/([a-fA-F0-9])/?$ admin/load/loadsearch.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/load/loaddSearch/([a-fA-F0-9])/([a-fA-F0-9])/(.*)$ admin/load/loadsearch.php?type=$1&id=$2&lname=$3 [L]
```